# Componente encima de otros ,android

Tags: android, android-studio, botón

tengo un problema en android studio, tengo dos fragments en los cuales el primer fragment envia datos al segundo fragment, lo que pasa es que al cargar el segundo fragment me aparece un boton que pertenece al primer fragment. Y lo unico que hice fui recibir los datos enviados a traves de ellos.

Primer Fragment
[image: Fragment A]

Segundo Fragment
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado al ejecutar el proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo del segundo fragment
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, para encontrar el problema sera mejor que en lugar de mostrar la imagen de los layouts pongas el xml (escribe siempre los xml manualmente, usar la interfaz grafica solo te traera problemas). Ademas muestranos el codigo de como abres el segundo fragment. Imagino que con esto encontraremos el problema enseguida.

Comment: Hola Jean, acostumbra agregar el código como texto no como imagen, te sugiero revises [ask], nuevamente.